# restore list of sql bk

Tags: database, restore

I want to restore list of sql databases .bak from file

tried to use this script, but for single DB , I need to get list of all databases and restore them .

```
USE [master]
GO
RESTORE DATABASE DB_Clients
FROM DISK = 'C:\OldDBClients.bak'
```

Comment: Do you have any specific question about this? Is this in any way related to programming?